# ASP.NET CORE Web API: Model value is null when doing HTTP Post requests with null Guid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm facing a problem doing post requests via ASP.NET Core Web API. I'm a bit confused of the articles I read/found while Googling.

So here's my scenario:

I'm trying to do a HTTP Post request to an api endpoint with a complex parameter.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/createstudent")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateStudent([FromBody]Student student)
    {
        // Service logic
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }

    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that every time I make a post request to this endpoint the model value is null if I pass below the object.

```
{"studentId": null,"studentName": "Sam"}
```

Whereas If I pass empty Guid as below, I am able to get the model.

```
{ "studentId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "studentName": "Sam" }
```

Is this a bug in ASP.NET Core 2? As I was able to pass null / Empty Guid for StudentId in .NET Framework WEB API.

Comment: You should make the property nullable if your want to allow `null`

Comment: The same behavior is happening for DateTime parameter as well.

Comment: Can't we send null value for non nullable property in .net core? as we can send in .NET Framework.

Comment: make it as nullable field or have some default value for this field. public Guid? StudentId { get; set; }

Comment: You also need to omit the value in the request - i.e. just `{ "studentName": "Sam" }`

Comment: Guid is a value type, it does not allow null. You need to use `Guid?`.

Comment: @wannadream, Yes. However, I am not facing the problem in framework API. Is it the problem with .NET Core?

Comment: @BalanjaneyuluK Maybe. If the difference does exist, you may question it to .NET Core team in GitHub.

Comment: I was able discover a workaround to a problem that appears very similar; maybe identical. I'm not sure whether this might assist your problem, however, I'm hoping that it might; at some level. - Cheers > **Post**
> > [ASP.NET MVC Core Web POST Request populating Data Model with NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56828127/asp-net-mvc-core-web-post-request-populating-data-model-with-null-values)