# ASP.NET MVC Core Web POST Request populating Data Model with NULL values

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

## Scenario

I'm setting up a blog and am configuring a page to POST edited comments to an MsSql server.

### Issue

After I submit submit a form POST, via my view, the property values that are supposed to be captured and returned via this form, are all returned as "NULL"!? This eventually causes an exception error due to there being NULL values present within my data model. After stepping through my entire application, and using Fiddler, I am unable to diagnose the issue.

### Quick Visual Example

> After a `POST` has been submitted (during run-time) and my application has reached the **Home Controller** of my blog, this is what's shown and available.

- [Captured Form Data - Seen through Visual Studio's local inspector](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g-Fk-vaXW0NzczSDHrMM7DTgdeoz6rDI/view?usp=sharing)
- [POST data received in Home Controller](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fQq_xXLvuaTQ_3nDOoezEf7ottUtdX7p/view?usp=sharing)

**Note:** as you can see, each input's value is captured by the Home Controller during run-time. However, this data is not transferred to the *EditComment* method post `POST`.

### Process

Input controls are populated with property values for my model, then submitted:

> **EditComments.cs**

```html
    @model MpComment

    ... HTML Content ...

    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="EditComment" method="post" class="text-danger input-form">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="<Model.Property>" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="<Model.Property>" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="<Model.Property>" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        ... ASP Form Input Elements...

        <div class="form-group input-submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn material-button" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

My AppDbContext is initialized

> **AppDbContext.cs**

```cs
namespace Portfolio.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public virtual DbSet<MpPost> MpPost { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<MpComment> MpComment { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<MpGuest> MpGuest { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<MpLogin> MpLogin { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<MpProject> MpProject { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My MpComments model begins to appear to move through and set each properties value, however, the data that populates each property is NULL.

```cs
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace Portfolio.Models
    {
        public partial class MpComment
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int Mp_Post_Id { get; set; }
            public int Mp_Guest_Id { get; set; }
            public string Comment { get; set; }
            public int? Karma { get; set; }
            public int? Approved { get; set; }
            public string Ip { get; set; }
            public string Agent { get; set; }
            public DateTime? Create { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
            public DateTime? Update { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

Once nothing gets populated, the Home Controller is initiated, and the following function is called:

> **HomeController.cs**

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditComment(MpComment comment)
    {
        comment.Id = 0;

        _repo.AddComment(comment);

        if (await _repo.SaveChangesAsync())
            return RedirectToAction("ViewComments");
        else
            return View(comment);
    }
```

It's at this point where the *comment* parameter variable populated from the POST contains only NULL values, and appears like so:

### Investigation & Analysis

#### VisualStudio

- Local Variable Inspector

```
    Agent        null
    Approved     null
    Comment      null
    Create       {6/30/2019 1:04:29 PM}
    Id           0
    Ip           null
    Karma        null
    Mp_Guest_Id  0
    Mp_Post_Id   0
    Update       {6/30/2019 1:04:29 PM}
```

This procedure works as expected on other procedures set to accomplish this exact same feature, just on a different table!?

For example, here's what Fiddler captured on a successful POST, from an almost identical POST'ing procedure:

#### Fiddler Inspector

- Raw *(Success for EditProject)*

```
    POST https://localhost:44390/Home/EditProject/21 HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:44390
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 555
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Origin: https://localhost:44390
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
    Referer: https://localhost:44390/Home/EditProject/21
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,mt;q=0.8
    Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.x5eNnYCJ5UA=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMrl1aZfFqqMphsPHMioPYeJIj8tRRSXB1N9Pm7JhspsKDyUKawAVJYkSlP56myEU4qcRohQ1axrDWFXPVvZjlNZqiRZAZVOMcZ3wupV12M_z289E7MaUrZ1nbOzH34eiH0; .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMp2YqORrHzf5IL0rLJ8jvAP-RYvHIXeH63EfD3-TugdZGBP9nf_lHhAn71ACsIQZe_cJ1x7u3FBh25uhlXZIJX9yk7ZdH_GuwfYEe-Zaa1CSAD2f2g8U7syt8jvxy18c-qCN9Yq2zLQpBeOlzftudcaMKKrsA-UGO8BOHLPTk1TYe1QMosDGaFDLXY0POqCpluxiiA0qsA0i9iQeAP6HL7ZC8lLjf76Lf_E5usVyakwa9X3ELDJQeaEFFa5Vi_5063xCHhm3NRREE5loUCff1rKmaOKvvOR-Fnf-QtYLG-MGthgVAGah4cdXjD0jsKFBM0Ny-Yt8uRddQ26w_8AUJqhRo9jOAXEuzyhYwPRfKQKykgpy-4lVIZXc2QR25EWxq9H6zh5GGCTIitxISDcpoHf0mUqzT9aJKo_LwB6cibzbDwBmVsTc6Yn6cQA0MMoBVa6E6hKuvQoNerU7psX5z2D2k8tB8mZVlJQ3medeMwHQonOSBh99OxOrBO5K6iedlpPqSNco8r7PbNcHCdhLKehtoyJkE3tzmrv_EOTAS7ldXNhhPHqNp_RmuAdGWlsJ-a-bN5itj1hv_o7RCxl8t49XB9oddsg4iOvR-BUZOLuxJKfQ90PAH4S9BvblwLKoXx3Gt3We5WeG8Ga6rAXHQhd

    Id=0&Title=Product+Engineer&Desc=nulla+neque+libero+convallis+eget+eleifend&Live_Url=bloglovin.com%2Feget%2Ftincidunt%2Feget.jpg&Github_Repo=sourceforge.net%2Fet%2Fultrices%2Fposuere%2Fcubilia.jpg&Bitbucket_Repo=creativecommons.org%2Fpede%2Flibero%2Fquis.html&Create=2011-07-11T00%3A00%3A00.000&Update=2019-06-20T00%3A00%3A00.000&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMqTHmlRblU70EY0Ou7tH2IifiXdJOCtMRepfMg-GhKz-j4at6h9BOzJTNjHIROMjDpUiOqxvDeGWcja8K-uGkYrW8DX58j9mIFlwKML9tLVtvusmGmPekVMPxYqRkKdcyLGb6qpav3upDLAvfxLblbs9RynCyG4bDTAAZ4jzxc-ww
```

#### Fiddler Inspector

- Raw *(Failure for EditComments)*

```
    POST https://localhost:44390/Home/EditComment/1 HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:44390
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 606
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Origin: https://localhost:44390
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
    Referer: https://localhost:44390/Home/EditComment/1
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,mt;q=0.8
    Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.x5eNnYCJ5UA=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMrl1aZfFqqMphsPHMioPYeJIj8tRRSXB1N9Pm7JhspsKDyUKawAVJYkSlP56myEU4qcRohQ1axrDWFXPVvZjlNZqiRZAZVOMcZ3wupV12M_z289E7MaUrZ1nbOzH34eiH0; .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMp2YqORrHzf5IL0rLJ8jvAP-RYvHIXeH63EfD3-TugdZGBP9nf_lHhAn71ACsIQZe_cJ1x7u3FBh25uhlXZIJX9yk7ZdH_GuwfYEe-Zaa1CSAD2f2g8U7syt8jvxy18c-qCN9Yq2zLQpBeOlzftudcaMKKrsA-UGO8BOHLPTk1TYe1QMosDGaFDLXY0POqCpluxiiA0qsA0i9iQeAP6HL7ZC8lLjf76Lf_E5usVyakwa9X3ELDJQeaEFFa5Vi_5063xCHhm3NRREE5loUCff1rKmaOKvvOR-Fnf-QtYLG-MGthgVAGah4cdXjD0jsKFBM0Ny-Yt8uRddQ26w_8AUJqhRo9jOAXEuzyhYwPRfKQKykgpy-4lVIZXc2QR25EWxq9H6zh5GGCTIitxISDcpoHf0mUqzT9aJKo_LwB6cibzbDwBmVsTc6Yn6cQA0MMoBVa6E6hKuvQoNerU7psX5z2D2k8tB8mZVlJQ3medeMwHQonOSBh99OxOrBO5K6iedlpPqSNco8r7PbNcHCdhLKehtoyJkE3tzmrv_EOTAS7ldXNhhPHqNp_RmuAdGWlsJ-a-bN5itj1hv_o7RCxl8t49XB9oddsg4iOvR-BUZOLuxJKfQ90PAH4S9BvblwLKoXx3Gt3We5WeG8Ga6rAXHQhd

    Mp_Post_Id=1&Mp_Guest_Id=1&Comment=lorem+quisque+ut+erat+curabitur+gravida+nisi+at+nibh+in+hac+habitasse+platea+dictumst+aliquam&Karma=1&Approved=1&Ip=21.99.31.96&Agent=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Macintosh%3B+U%3B+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_7%3B+en-us%29+AppleWebKit%2F533.4+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.1+Safari%2F533.4&Create=2018-07-17T00%3A00%3A00.000&Update=2012-06-01T00%3A00%3A00.000&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMquggjJDBhMvQwfCKwHRJS9tJeBi-4bT19jJVjuUjZgYE1LD4BvCF2LBJlQ45u3d9sEGmm-l9EAhbXaA2TwuNjW4xhYpVXl4Z0YE_YBEvbuSzodxjP8v1GoYAXYfs5yl3L39SK0gp1YKkkwujMhdExO17v3n-b_y4IhhZJ3SanIZw
```

**Note:** Everything appears identical (where it should), except there's a discrepancy with the POST URL. Each time I troubleshoot this, I take the 1st entry, edit it, and then submit it. Each time I do this (on the four other procedures where this works fine), it iterates to the next entry; as seen above.

**Example:**
   A) Edit & Submit **Project 1** when there's *20 Project entries*:

```
POST https://localhost:44390/Home/EditProject/21 <=== discrepancy
```

B) Edit & Submit **Comment 1** when there's *20 Comment entries*:

```
POST https://localhost:44390/Home/EditComment/1 <=== discrepancy
```

### **Chrome (Network Headers)**

> **Success** (Project)

```
General:
    Request URL: https://localhost:44390/Home/EditProject/66
    Request Method: POST
    Status Code: 302
    Remote Address: [::1]:44390
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Response Headers:
    content-length: 0
    date: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 00:04:16 GMT
    location: /Home/ViewProjects
    server: Kestrel
    status: 302
    x-powered-by: ASP.NET
    x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcV29ya3NwYWNlXHd3d1xhc3BcUG9ydGZvbGlvXFBvcnRmb2xpb1xIb21lXEVkaXRQcm9qZWN0XDY2?=
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Request Headers:
    :authority: localhost:44390
    :method: POST
    :path: /Home/EditProject/66
    :scheme: https
    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,mt;q=0.8
    cache-control: max-age=0
    content-length: 1200
    content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.x5eNnYCJ5UA=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMrl1aZfFqqMphsPHMioPYeJIj8tRRSXB1N9Pm7JhspsKDyUKawAVJYkSlP56myEU4qcRohQ1axrDWFXPVvZjlNZqiRZAZVOMcZ3wupV12M_z289E7MaUrZ1nbOzH34eiH0; .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMpTJYFjUyUy3eLO3fbnX9V4SSq14P_h_AlTAyZs-9LrMW9QOzTP46d8CJetHqzamw-ulm6IbjGyC_hElFiwtJRbKAV3GuVlGQeNfbhcJ7M81EH4bqnbi-NBwP4nmlXROTG3DvMYdHqC1-eqT53ip4mnHpdLDLKlwX80Lk8uWPpiyD5L_RFiMGl5i0vOUz19bbn-mSC3IVbuGz8LeDePfKDmU-3b8_sNiZJpBpx4p6jORrds69LkpkdZX2NUWzyevM4TWw8irVRRBY0PAFKkkZEfQy52kPFfHLZgcZ2JMFo2iQ0DqRcq7nqwnU1JRbNTHEQ56WOsStWn7IGfBqA43B5QdLn-yWTiP5AIalG3kv_o-6VZTmyfu6QbBCbwD_7gpjewoB8IiYn86WaTVbvkryGBJZMjSEq5M2H1m365zI392lNZVzwDADwF04s4zYmHx8snkk9Z3NUAjvzDJo9b1IJNNIKnPmERysOR73W_hAfZdpVN0Ltx2fT7-13g4ow-2Xizi_t2b4SQcX6tC_tlju224eh0KkKNxOJ3irBQRsWAT9iKe_aaE7usFUkZgfR9vuZnPO62qzuxUwROsX3-Tz4lSxSD2N4ajqpEpVMcS528hMO5lXQwMA2RpGBKpR2JJzsN1KdbYgPcB16Ad14VgJNJ
    origin: https://localhost:44390
    referer: https://localhost:44390/Home/EditProject/66
    upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Form Data:
    Title: Product Engineer
    Desc: nulla neque libero convallis eget eleifend
    Content: sodales scelerisque mauris sit amet eros suspendisse accumsan tortor quis turpis sed ante vivamus tortor duis mattis egestas metus aenean fermentum donec ut mauris eget massa tempor convallis nulla neque libero convallis eget eleifend luctus ultricies eu nibh quisque id justo sit amet sapien dignissim vestibulum vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae nulla dapibus dolor vel est donec odio justo sollicitudin ut suscipit a feugiat et eros vestibulum ac est lacinia nisi venenatis tristique fusce congue diam id ornare
    Project_Image: http://dummyimage.com/193x141.jpg/ff4444/ffffff
    Live_Url: bloglovin.com/eget/tincidunt/eget.jpg
    Github_Repo: sourceforge.net/et/ultrices/posuere/cubilia.jpg
    Bitbucket_Repo: creativecommons.org/pede/libero/quis.html
    Create: 2011-07-11T00:00:00.000
    Update: 2019-06-20T00:00:00.000
    __RequestVerificationToken: CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMq4kGmbGOLj875J5O8hQlwLIYQR7YHYe58lgzEyN5Wat3viIjRuF80IPiwf_iRYUydAC0vfWv-q5jvLA_bAsdz7blAbvNoT4TxTYqZ5ONf5Q2bYqOyWlhdoN7ZduEaRc3dEBua_8F35F6mNuq0NFfLTDkvlCvO1da4dbhsWg49nsg
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> **Failure** (Comment)

```
General:
    Request URL: https://localhost:44390/Home/EditComment/20
    Request Method: POST
    Status Code: 500
    Remote Address: [::1]:44390
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Response Headers:
    content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    date: Sun, 30 Jun 2019 23:40:23 GMT
    server: Kestrel
    status: 500
    x-powered-by: ASP.NET
    x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcV29ya3NwYWNlXHd3d1xhc3BcUG9ydGZvbGlvXFBvcnRmb2xpb1xIb21lXEVkaXRDb21tZW50XDIw?=
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Request Headers:
    :authority: localhost:44390
    :method: POST
    :path: /Home/EditComment/20
    :scheme: https
    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,mt;q=0.8
    cache-control: max-age=0
    content-length: 558
    content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.x5eNnYCJ5UA=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMrl1aZfFqqMphsPHMioPYeJIj8tRRSXB1N9Pm7JhspsKDyUKawAVJYkSlP56myEU4qcRohQ1axrDWFXPVvZjlNZqiRZAZVOMcZ3wupV12M_z289E7MaUrZ1nbOzH34eiH0; .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMpTJYFjUyUy3eLO3fbnX9V4SSq14P_h_AlTAyZs-9LrMW9QOzTP46d8CJetHqzamw-ulm6IbjGyC_hElFiwtJRbKAV3GuVlGQeNfbhcJ7M81EH4bqnbi-NBwP4nmlXROTG3DvMYdHqC1-eqT53ip4mnHpdLDLKlwX80Lk8uWPpiyD5L_RFiMGl5i0vOUz19bbn-mSC3IVbuGz8LeDePfKDmU-3b8_sNiZJpBpx4p6jORrds69LkpkdZX2NUWzyevM4TWw8irVRRBY0PAFKkkZEfQy52kPFfHLZgcZ2JMFo2iQ0DqRcq7nqwnU1JRbNTHEQ56WOsStWn7IGfBqA43B5QdLn-yWTiP5AIalG3kv_o-6VZTmyfu6QbBCbwD_7gpjewoB8IiYn86WaTVbvkryGBJZMjSEq5M2H1m365zI392lNZVzwDADwF04s4zYmHx8snkk9Z3NUAjvzDJo9b1IJNNIKnPmERysOR73W_hAfZdpVN0Ltx2fT7-13g4ow-2Xizi_t2b4SQcX6tC_tlju224eh0KkKNxOJ3irBQRsWAT9iKe_aaE7usFUkZgfR9vuZnPO62qzuxUwROsX3-Tz4lSxSD2N4ajqpEpVMcS528hMO5lXQwMA2RpGBKpR2JJzsN1KdbYgPcB16Ad14VgJNJ
    origin: https://localhost:44390
    referer: https://localhost:44390/Home/EditComment/20
    upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Form Data:
    Mp_Post_Id: 20
    Mp_Guest_Id: 20
    Comment: etiam faucibus cursus urna ut tellus nulla ut erat id mauris vulputate elementum nullam varius nulla
    Karma: 6
    Approved: 0
    Ip: 142.146.130.50
    Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20120405 Firefox/14.0a1
    Create: 2010-10-21T00:00:00.000
    Update: 2009-10-07T00:00:00.000
    __RequestVerificationToken: CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMpEiWlpyDJHiDaw7Rz0PI6fyiscJ9aAahlk0J2Coz5R42uB-L3LvBS94t5QxvcBZ2PwMUI9McLlFR1rtds9yh89UZSzHpR-q_SvbM1g4KCUYDhvNht_bMaoy9NJvMTfOCR_TPW4CKTMnJCR8OEJYahY9CWXY_GozMl1MMkL3MFkFQ
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### **Wireshark (Traffic Analysis)**

> **Success** (Edit Project)

```
POST /Home/EditProject/2 HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,mt;q=0.8
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.x5eNnYCJ5UA=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMrl1aZfFqqMphsPHMioPYeJIj8tRRSXB1N9Pm7JhspsKDyUKawAVJYkSlP56myEU4qcRohQ1axrDWFXPVvZjlNZqiRZAZVOMcZ3wupV12M_z289E7MaUrZ1nbOzH34eiH0; .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMqPm6KX-2uhTXr62WeE6Jia-lF8RtuWQCtjegxTJyf6k-wmUcVdvsBAhEuLKWMN_ttD6dPUr-E8QGJPI_2fD0vYnbo6ADWRXWlMFHwloQ43bPBuSn0zPyp6rZvQLaYFXQXO2aO9Kk7UF64Nh4-kJenvCOcPYtv5JS5HneYXgXO_hM26wnG-3my6SaA4ApdBYndK4DbrdB4393HtLK1579yg7ON12bDIBH71pTMdK6UuIvAI1Bh3HbkUuCOtJzZ3ZqB_JQAutgRe6z6nFGcdPMcb0VbIUPa9USyg0oUJ9KxNPspX9y_dAt4GO18OrsFd-s8d-oWV7zDEMpQVBpLoaVk23xpiObUlVLfS-OQhfVgq3RAXAfkZOR7B7eusFkr3I_ZQRb__76x8dVRvHDy-gy_2ZU1xNJve0v-L38kRsVKoXpjCfc9HW9CaVZvoOH6YB1x-gwsGB_eJ8IJsMTnscrNhDloNlel42K7q8GlA-lTK9yXgiXqLm2VAYdpCf_b45ixMba0Cr7umLyMBzf7BEo3J5uNEAYvF7qN5DOlTSbuvwP33ZbBQJyu3uwnfi4JdzYHNDtlZJqlgUkVgmw_3snp3oJxizU50DFgTUyPjAuB71aEOEyVQRXbgZbJ_S-TzLddHc-hjZarUqKK6n5MBX-8_
Host: localhost:44390
Referer: https://localhost:44390/Home/EditProject/2
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
origin: https://localhost:44390
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN: 2a6aebc6-e154-4f02-9517-cae788a1069f
X-Forwarded-For: [::1]:60639
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Content-Length: 710

Title=Senior+Quality+Engineer+IV&Desc=nascetur+ridiculus+mus+vivamus+vestibulum+sagittis+sapien+cum+sociis&Content=vivamus+tortor+duis+mattis+egestas+metus+aenean+fermentum+donec+ut+mauris+eget&Project_Image=http%3A%2F%2Fdummyimage.com%2F237x180.bmp%2F5fa2dd%2Fffffff&Live_Url=ihg.com%2Fgravida%2Fnisi%2Fat%2Fnibh.json&Github_Repo=paginegialle.it%2Fligula%2Fsuspendisse.xml&Bitbucket_Repo=harvard.edu%2Fcongue.aspx&Create=2018-09-07T00%3A00%3A00.000&Update=2013-05-17T00%3A00%3A00.000&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMqFkSNAgkReKvXjTW0EStR_OB4Zz6j90ZdieDNspaE86824rUys1Av2cI9mKtO15RaMnYSiz1_As63Ez0XWxX4N3zfL4vlgGfPQ43FMqqfcPBAG33xvi4G0naOTHEVTdGbiwkLrK2UVF2O01JzfVW3olYbxna45Pg10haFTI-s5QgHTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 16:19:16 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 0
Location: /Home/ViewProjects
```

> **Failure** (Edit Comments)

```
POST /Home/EditComment/1 HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,mt;q=0.8
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.x5eNnYCJ5UA=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMrl1aZfFqqMphsPHMioPYeJIj8tRRSXB1N9Pm7JhspsKDyUKawAVJYkSlP56myEU4qcRohQ1axrDWFXPVvZjlNZqiRZAZVOMcZ3wupV12M_z289E7MaUrZ1nbOzH34eiH0; .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMqsILl7uDq3qp0MgEGexCwq_b2cNi4376Wt5jxWgINpwDxVRedde5wkOvqycIGfKrQJM2uCVgFMc75i-3Ch_Sct3wFtj_o2wHjLt9OSgM1dieKWdY8BVsLWGHIsMkceMbh_GQz6xJsKrOixjijHUw88p990DPKm2dGJo-JLSHJpqxGNkQxlhPNPf-VsHEQmh27Mn2ah_NZj0NqIlxDuxfmeLQoV0W1s99zVg7URMUbSmGQsShrT1HxhcUjesLuGnyy90GdxmFyGf2-RKPl1zGdkQhaIgicmxQi-bR8otlu5E1uHPms-_HR3xZwT3koowKFYNM4NFHfPuQOwPgZooHCJeaYvweHuqiB5Oh98c6gRHalMSUqGApIICOfVY7mrr9uxt70PeB60PisyAfASCClKf0IsnJLh8flRZ5lr7cr4fhVXU9Jn-PS_09-iX262WvSgjWiPvfe6W_3QxhnPV1NBb0xVy7FCBNMeIIge0BftQzGMb0h_2xsCITwf9oAApXH-uTnC4E2FZI1nUzdfRVPCrj0kXsppeVr6q-65d9_cWgh2aDC4EYeCF4v__Yz9IZPoMKCvHF_rq_Vna4jLPLsobt4VcViYrSY66JmtO9IeoXpA3Ivd2P7ws4lcnJ9STgFV4oP3hmC4aRdA1BURRzz2
Host: localhost:44390
Referer: https://localhost:44390/Home/EditComment/1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
origin: https://localhost:44390
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN: 2a6aebc6-e154-4f02-9517-cae788a1069f
X-Forwarded-For: [::1]:61219
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Content-Length: 606

Mp_Post_Id=1&Mp_Guest_Id=1&Comment=lorem+quisque+ut+erat+curabitur+gravida+nisi+at+nibh+in+hac+habitasse+platea+dictumst+aliquam&Karma=1&Approved=1&Ip=21.99.31.96&Agent=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Macintosh%3B+U%3B+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_7%3B+en-us%29+AppleWebKit%2F533.4+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.1+Safari%2F533.4&Create=2018-07-17T00%3A00%3A00.000&Update=2012-06-01T00%3A00%3A00.000&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8OfA6sTjcU1PuqxxzGM-oMr9nzkkEn5p6n7jwRflZ1bmxhEOVzWiW7VXO1rmDYbHQR4CvYlmqH4LyuHMPDsQZWXE-gZ3eDU2LWqJd1uVnMKeJcbV0gne1gxSQdeg2Cd7wklVGIJAlC4PNr5hbqJmAGItiemNRukLVKMLVZ0E65dR-pVhxKy4SteMmvnDVMg5_QHTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 17:06:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

## Additional Information

### **Project Configuration**

> **myProject.csproj**

```html
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.9" />
        <PackageReference Include="MySql.data" Version="8.0.16" />
        <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.16" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
      </ItemGroup>

    </Project>
```

### Database

> **[mpComment.sql]**

```sql
    CREATE TABLE [mpComment]
    (
        [id]            INT             NOT NULL        PRIMARY KEY,
        [mp_post_id]    INT             NOT NULL        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES mpPost(id),
        [mp_guest_id]   INT             NOT NULL        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES mpGuest(id),
        [comment]       NVARCHAR(500)   NOT NULL,
        [karma]         INT             NULL,
        [approved]      INT             NOT NULL,
        [ip]            NVARCHAR(100)   NULL,
        [agent]         NVARCHAR(255)   NULL,
        [create]        DATETIME        NULL,
        [update]        DATETIME        NULL,
    )
```

#### Insertion Query

> **CommentsInsertQuery.sql**
>
> This would be *exactly* the same data that would be (typically) submitted through the aforementioned form; which works fine.

```sql
    INSERT INTO [profileDb].[dbo].[mpComment] ([mp_post_id], [mp_guest_id], [comment], [karma], [approved], [ip], [agent], [create], [update])
    VALUES (1, 1, 'lorem quisque ut erat curabitur gravida nisi at nibh in hac habitasse platea dictumst aliquam', 1, 1, '21.99.31.96', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_7; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.1 Safari/533.4', '07/17/2018', '06/01/2012');
```

## Final Thoughts

I am concerned that this issue might be occurring somewhere within the Entity Framework, where I cannot troubleshoot. If I had a sincere point of origin where I can identify exact point where the data from my browser is captured by the .Net framework, I might be able to better identify the key issue.

### Similar Post:

> [ASP.NET CORE Web API: Model value is null when doing HTTP Post requests with null Guid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441075/asp-net-core-web-api-model-value-is-null-when-doing-http-post-requests-with-nul)
>
> > This question is very similar to an alternate question, however, there appears to be less troubleshooting, and a lot less information concerning the matter. In addition, there was not much love on this question, and no solutions provided.

Thanks in advance, and cheers

Comment: If your model is being populated with null values, then surely the issue must lie in the way .NET converts your *post values* into your *model values* i.e. for some reason it is unable to translate the values in the post into a valid model. Entity Framework and SQL Server only become involved *after* that stage, so if I am understanding correctly I think you can safely say its nothing to do with either of them.

Comment: It looks like from your Fiddle, that you are posting the values within the query string, instead of within the body of the post? I guess that should work, but its not the normal way to do it. And you might have to use the [FromUri] attribute to tell the parser to look there.

Comment: And your *comment* post doesn't contain an `id` which according to your model is a required property, so it might be as simple as the fact that you've left that out. Whereas if you look at the Fiddle for your *project* post the first field is `id`.

Comment: The database auto-increments the `id`, so, either an `id` = 0 or no `id` is submitted at all, and it will post correctly. For example, look at my **Insertion Query** above, where there's no Id, however, that _does_ insert a record. I've tried this with other insertions; e.g., for projects.

Comment: Attempting editing and submitting a Project post (without the `id`), as I would a Comment post, and everything from asp.net MVC appears to work correctly. Fiddler output:

`Title=Senior+Quality+Engineer&Desc=nascetur+ridiculus+mus+vivamus+vestibulum+sagittis+sapien+cum+sociis&Content=vivamus+tortor+duis+mattis+egestas+metus+aenean+fermentum+donec+ut+mauris+eget&Project_Image=http%3A%2F%2Fdummyimage.com%2F237x180.bmp%2F5fa2dd%2Fffffff&Live_Url=ihg.com%2Fgravida%2Fnisi%2Fat%2Fnibh.json&Github_Repo=11111111111111111&Bitbucket_Repo=harvard.edu%2Fcongue.aspx&Create=2018-09-07T00%3A00%3A00.000&U`

Comment: The problem isn't whether the eventual null values would be accepted, however, that the data being `POST`'ed is either a `null` || `0` value; rather than the values submitted via the EditComments.cshtml form. This issue doesn't occur on 4 other operations that do this exact same feat, for Guests, Projects, Posts, and Login. None of these models accept a `null` value for their `id` either. i.e. `public int? Id { get; set; }`. In addition, I don't know any other way to `POST` data from ASP. I'm new to both ASP & MVC, and don't understand how (only) this procedure is dumps data.

Comment: Unrelated, but are you sure you are using SQL Server? You reference `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore`

Comment: In Object Explorer, it shows (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB (SQL Server 13.0.4001)

Comment: The post you reference appears to have exactly the same issue as you are facing, and the required solution is there in the comments - you must provide a value for all non-nullable value type properties in your model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Jerry Rigged Solution

I was able to manage a workaround, albeit, I'm still not certain "why" this error is occurring.

### Synopsis

Sense the post-back data was being captured within the application **([Graphic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g-Fk-vaXW0NzczSDHrMM7DTgdeoz6rDI/view))**, however, it was not populating the parameter value of the `EditComments` method, I simply populated the data manually.

### Solution

Included the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` library within my Home Controller, and modified the following post-back `method` from:

> **HomeController.cs**

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditComment(MpComment comment)
    {
        comment.Id = 0;

        _repo.AddComment(comment);

        if (await _repo.SaveChangesAsync())
            return RedirectToAction("ViewComments");
        else
            return View(comment);
    }
```

to

> **HomeController.cs**

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditComment()
    {
        var form = Request.Form.ToList();

        var comment = new MpComment
        {
            Id          = 0,
            Mp_Post_Id  = Int32.Parse(form.Where(x => x.Key == "Mp_Post_Id").FirstOrDefault().Value),
            Mp_Guest_Id = Int32.Parse(form.Where(x => x.Key == "Mp_Guest_Id").FirstOrDefault().Value),
            Comment     = form.Where(x => x.Key == "Comment").FirstOrDefault().Value,
            Karma       = Int32.Parse(form.Where(x => x.Key == "Karma").FirstOrDefault().Value),
            Approved    = Int32.Parse(form.Where(x => x.Key == "Approved").FirstOrDefault().Value),
            Ip          = form.Where(x => x.Key == "Ip").FirstOrDefault().Value,
            Agent       = form.Where(x => x.Key == "Agent").FirstOrDefault().Value,
            Create      = Convert.ToDateTime(form.Where(x => x.Key == "Create").FirstOrDefault().Value),
            Update      = Convert.ToDateTime(form.Where(x => x.Key == "Update").FirstOrDefault().Value)
        };

        _repo.AddComment(comment);

        if (await _repo.SaveChangesAsync())
            return RedirectToAction("ViewComments");
        else
            return View(comment);
    }
```

...and everything works as expected.

#### Additional note

These values were easy enough to retrieve, in case anyone else has a similar issue. Simply convert the request form data into a `List` (as above) and print out those results via the output console.

**Example:**

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public methodExpectingPostback()
    {
        var form = Request.Form.ToList();

        foreach (var item in form)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Key} : {item.Value}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

```
public ValuesController : ApiController
{
     public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri] GeoPoint location) { ... }
}
```

In ASP.Net you should use FromUri. It tells the parser to look for the object in the URL. 
You can also use FromBody to tell the parser to look for the objects in the request body.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why I would approach things this way!? I'm not transmitting my data via a `GET`, rather a `POST`. Please elaborate upon how this would correct the `null` values issue.

Comment: @NobleCloud It won't help - the reason both Steve and I suggested that was because Fiddler made it look like you were doing a post with the data in the query string. Its possible you might need the [FromBody] attribute. But fundamentally the issue is that .NET is unable to convert the post data sent into your object model - I believe because of the missing Id. I'm unsure why you wouldn't at least try that to rule it out.

Comment: No luck either, after including a `[FromBody]` attribute, rather than receiving a `500` result, a `415` (unsupported media type) error results from the server. With respects towards the absent Primary Key `id`. The DB is set to `auto_increment` all new records, and fails once a `PK` value is passed; to create a new row. This is why it's not passed. Can't quite understand why this process works on every other table, than this one. One thing to note (too), this is the only table with `FK`s, however, I created this table, with `FK`s, and it still error-ed out!?